# JSONから必要な要素のみを抜き出したい

Tags: c#, json

Json.NETを用いて、あるAPIから取得したJSONの要素は以下のようになっています。

```js
{ "array": [ ["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"] ] }
```

ここからC#で、"array"内n番目のリストのうち、b番目・c番目を出力するとしたらどう記述したらいいんでしょうか。

```
bn
cn
```

keyがある分には整形こなせたんですが（{"aaa" : 1, "bbb" : 2}といった形式）。

また、それぞれの要素を選択してリスト化もしたいのです。
例えばb番目 と c番目だけのリスト:

```
b1, c1
b2, c2
```

初学者でもあり混乱中です。ご教授くださいませ。

---

現時点でのコード(Unityに書いているスクリプトなのでこうなっています):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class flights : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        String url = "http://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?adsb=1&mlat=1&faa=1&flarm=1&estimated=1&air=1&gnd=1&vehicles=1&gliders=1&array=1";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        Stream response_stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response_stream);

        var obj = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
        obj.Remove("full_count");
        obj.Remove("version");
        obj.Remove("copyright");

        Debug.Log(obj);
    }
```

**APIへのリクエスト例**
`http://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?adsb=1&mlat=1&faa=1&flarm=1&estimated=1&air=1&gnd=1&vehicles=1&gliders=1&array=1`

**APIから返されるJSONの例**

```js
{
  "aircraft": [
    [
      "209f7487",
      "3443CE",
      28.9494,
      -13.6094,
      39,
      0,
      32,
      "7777",
      "F-GCRR7",
      "GRND",
      "NAVAIDS",
      1561348914,
      "",
      "",
      "",
      1,
      0,
      "7777XLAN",
      0
    ],
    [
      "209f7638",
      "49F10B",
      50.0864,
      14.1998,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      "4127",
      "F-LKPR7",
      "GRND",
      "",
      1561348911,
      "",
      "",
      "",
      1,
      0,
      "",
      0
    ],
```

Comment: 使用しているAPIにドキュメントはあるのでしょうか？ あるならそこにはschemaは定義されていますか？

Comment: 「出力する」がどのような行為・コードを求めているのかわかりませんでした。keyのある部分は「こなせた」とのことですが、挙げられたコードからは省略されており推測することもできませんでした。

Comment: あーすみません日本語が微妙で。要は、`{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`みたいになっていれば要素の抽出できるのに、`{"a" : [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]}`てなってるとどういうふうにすればいいのかわからなくなっているってことです。

Comment: 今吐けてるJSONでいうと`{ "aircraft" : [ [機体1情報], [機体2情報] ] }` となってます。これを 機体1情報 機体2情報... とリストにしていきたいんですが。

Comment: 細かい話ですが、APIを「吐く(=出力する)」のはあくまで提供元で、あなたは「取得」する側だと思います。 / 「整形」も「見やすく整える」イメージが強いので、「データを抜き出す」とかの方がやりたいことに近い表現になるかと。

Comment: なるほど。どうもありがとうございます！たすかります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この件に特化して簡単に言えば、`obj.GetValue("aircraft").ToList()`でリスト化できます。
その後は配列(JArray Class)としてアクセス出来ます。

`obj.Remove()`は不要です。以下のような感じですね。

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
var aclist = obj.GetValue("aircraft").ToList();

Console.WriteLine(aclist.Count.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(aclist[0]);
Console.WriteLine(aclist[0][2]);
```

表示結果の例はこんな感じで。

```
1500
[
  "209f7487",
  "3443CE",
  28.9494,
  -13.6094,
  39,
  0,
  32,
  "7777",
  "F-GCRR7",
  "GRND",
  "NAVAIDS",
  1561353334,
  "",
  "",
  "",
  1,
  0,
  "7777XLAN",
  0
]
28.9494
```

日本語の記事はこれくらいでしょうか。
[Flightradar24 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flightradar24)
[JSON - Flightradar24 から飛行中の航空機情報を取得！](https://www.mk-mode.com/blog/2016/02/08/fr24-getting-flight-info/)

Comment: 非常に簡潔で的確な回答どうもありがとうございます！たいへん助かりました。励みます！